# Есть ли возможность в React передать ref ссылку дочернего компонента в родительский компонент?

Tags: reactjs

В React есть так называемые ссылки ref. Их можно создавать в компоненте, пользоваться, или, к примеру, перенаправлять в дочерние компоненты через props.
А можно ли передать ref в родительский компонент? Если да, то посоветуйте, пожалуйста, источники, где можно узнать об этой теме больше.

Answer (score 0):

Навесить ref на дочерний компонент, а потом обратиться к его refs
как то так:

```
 this.refs.myChildComp.refs.targetComp
```